# Build failed: npm ERR! @google-cloud/firestore not accessible from firebase-admin

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I trying to deploy my cloud function, but some errors are showing up:

The error below is from Google Cloud Panel

> Build failed: npm ERR! @google-cloud/firestore not accessible from firebase-admin

The error below is from Firebase functions monitoring:

```
"status":{"code":3,"message":"Build failed: npm ERR! @google-cloud/firestore not accessible from firebase-admin\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2022-07-04T19_57_48_524Z-debug.log; Error ID: beaf8772"}
```

The error below is from terminal:

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        api(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
Error: There was an error deploying functions:
- Error Failed to update function api in region us-central1
```

The error below is from firestore-debug.log:

```
[info] ✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully 
[info] i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function api(us-central1)...
[debug] [2022-07-04T19:53:55.051Z] [update-us-central1-api] Retrying task index 0
[debug] [2022-07-04T19:54:25.656Z] [update-us-central1-api] Retrying task index 0
[debug] [2022-07-04T19:54:26.646Z] Got source token undefined for region us-central1
[debug] [2022-07-04T19:54:49.329Z] Total Function Deployment time: 56913
[debug] [2022-07-04T19:54:49.329Z] 2 Functions Deployed
[debug] [2022-07-04T19:54:49.329Z] 2 Functions Errored
[debug] [2022-07-04T19:54:49.329Z] 0 Function Deployments Aborted
[debug] [2022-07-04T19:54:49.329Z] Average Function Deployment time: 45578
[info] 
[info] Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    api(us-central1)
[debug] [2022-07-04T19:54:50.026Z] Missing URI for HTTPS function in printTriggerUrls. This shouldn't happen
[info] i  functions: cleaning up build files...
```

What is the real source of the error and how to solve it?

I appreciate any help!

**EDIT**

> I tried to edit the function directly from the Google Cloud Panel, but the same error is showing up.

Below is the reproducible code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({ msg: "hello world" })
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Below is the node and npm versions:

```
node --version
v14.16.0
npm --version
7.19.1
```

Below is the file package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^2.17.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.11.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I also tried to update the firebase-admin and firebase-functions packages, but no success.

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: undefined,
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.16.0', npm: '7.19.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

added 20 packages, removed 21 packages, changed 20 packages, and audited 351 packages in 19s

10 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

9 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 5 high, 1 critical)

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

npm audit fix
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: undefined,
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v14.16.0', npm: '7.19.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

removed 2 packages, changed 27 packages, and audited 349 packages in 7s

11 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: Could you please include a minimal reproducible code that can show that error. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've added some additional informations. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I just tried to deploy a simple http function like above, but the same error is been shown.

Comment: Could you please try to remove the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` and then run `npm install` again. See if the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything was working fine and suddenly the errors popped up.

I've solved it by updating my dependencies and also changing the node version in the package.json file.

I updated the node version to 14.16.0, but in the package.json file the node version was 10. So I've changed it to `"node": "14"` and now everything is working fine.

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^2.17.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.15.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.7"
  },
  "private": true
}
```